# convert ArrayList<Object[]> to Object[]

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

I'm searching for this problem since days and I can't seem to find a proper answer.
So I have an ArrayList of Arrays in form of Objects (ArrayList) filled with the result set of a SQL string. My goal is to convert the result of only one row into a one-dimensional Array of Objects.

I have tried several times my research results from this website, but the only knowledge I've made was how to convert a one-dimensional ArrayList to a simple array.
I hope you guys can help me in some ways. Thanks!

My table is looking like this:

```
sizeid | diameter
   1   |    32
   2   |    40
```

With the SQL-command "SELECT diameter FROM size" I'll get those two numbers 32 and 40, stored in a simple 2x1 table.

```
|  32  |
|  40  |
```

Now I want to have them in a one-dimensional Array.

the method to convert:

```
private Object[] getSizes() {
   query = new SQLquery();
   query.setSQLstring("SELECT diameter FROM size");
   query.runQuery();

   List<Object> sizeList = query.getRowData();
   Object[] sizes = new Object[sizeList.size()];

   // here I want to convert the List to an array..

   return sizes;
}
```

the method to generate the ArrayList of the class SQLquery:

```
public void outputResult() {
    try {
       if (result != null) {
          ResultSetMetaData meta = result.getMetaData();
          columns = meta.getColumnCount();
          columnNames = new Object[columns];
          for (int i=1; i<=columnNames.length; i++) {
             columnNames[i-1] = meta.getColumnName(i);
          }
          List<Object> rowData = new ArrayList<Object>();
          while (result.next()) {
            Object[] row = new Object[columns];
            for (int j=0; j<= columns; j++) {
               row[j-1] = result.getString(j);
            }
            rowData.add(row);
         }
      }
   } catch (SQLexception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
   }
}
```

and the simple get-method of the class SQLquery:

```
public List<Object> getRowData() {
   return rowData;
}
```

Comment: Object[] obj = myArrayList.get(0)

Comment: No, I think he wants an array with all the single-valued results from the query.

Comment: eclipse responses me this error message: "type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Object[]"

Comment: Something's wrong here: `for (int j=0; j<= columns; j++) row[j-1] = result.getString(j);` I believe `j` should start from 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, your `getRowData()` method returns a `List<Object>` whereas it actually contains arrays. Although this looks strange since you say it always returns a list of arrays, I'll assume that's what you have.

You need a loop which goes over these "objects", downcasting them to `Object[]`, and taking the first member.

```
Object[] sizes = new Object[sizeList.size()];
int i = 0;
for (Object o : sizeList) sizes[i++] = ((Object[]) o)[0];
return sizes;
```

Comment: Why is it strange that the items of the list of objects are arrays? Actually every item of the list of object is representing a resulting row of the SQL query: a row can contain multiple values (the column): this is only a special case where the query selects only one columns, and therefore we have arrays with only one item.

Comment: @Nicola It is not strange that the items in the list are arrays. What is strange is that the type of the said list is `List<Object>`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the approach what *Marko Topolnik* suggested.

However I would suggest to write your own "Table" class, which parses the result set and puts the values into an N*M dimensional array (or List) depending on your query. This way you can store meta information like the size of N or M dimension, etc.